# Observable.Buffer depending on buffered items

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I would like to buffer items in a sequence according to a condition. The problem is that this condition depends on the items that are processed.

Let me put an example:

Given this:

```
new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1 };
```

- If **n** is odd, stop buffering
- If **n** is even, start buffering

This way, the result sequence should be:

```
{ 1 }
{ 3 }
{ 5 }
{ 7 }
{ 2, 4, 6, 8 }
{ 1 }
```

I've tried variations of this without success:

```
var boundaries = origin.Select(x => x % 2 != 0).DistinctUntilChanged();
var result = origin.Buffer(boundaries);
```

Comment: Your question reminds me of this: [Buffer by time or running sum for reactive extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152134/buffer-by-time-or-running-sum-for-reactive-extensions).

Comment: In the example, the value `7` is missing from the output. Is this an oversight or it's intentional?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Oversighted. Sorry! Will fix it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be close to what you want. Instead of the `Buffer` operator it uses the `GroupByUntil` operator, which I consider to be [more reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492148/how-to-buffer-based-on-time-and-count-but-stopping-the-timer-if-no-events-occur#comment128888314_21492367).

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits the elements of a sequence into chunks that are starting with
/// elements that satisfy the predicate.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferByPredicate<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Predicate<TSource> startNewBufferPredicate)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(startNewBufferPredicate);
    return source
        .SelectMany(x =>
        {
            var subSequence = Observable.Return((Value: x, HasValue: true));
            if (startNewBufferPredicate(x))
                // Add a fake "boundary" element before the real element.
                subSequence = subSequence.Prepend((default, false));
            return subSequence;
        })
        .GroupByUntil(_ => 0, g => g.SkipWhile(e => e.HasValue))
        .SelectMany(g => g.Where(e => e.HasValue).Select(e => e.Value).ToArray())
        .Where(w => w.Length > 0);
}
```

Usage example:

```
 IObservable<IList<int>> result = origin.BufferByPredicate(x => x % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the results I'm getting with this method aren't correct. Using the data from the OP, I'm getting these groups.

`{ 1 }; { 3 }, { 4 }; { 5 }, { 2 }, { 4 }, { 6 }, { 8 }; { 1 }`

Ouch. It seems the comments cannot be formatted using multiple lines. I'd had to use semicolons as "newline".

Comment: @SuperJMN the `BufferByPredicate` is supposed to produce a group [7, 2, 4, 6, 8]. Unfortunately I can't confirm it right now because my PC has a problem.

Comment: That's strange. I hope you can try the code soon. Tested with `{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1 }` and got the results above.

Comment: @SuperJMN [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tNAkJc) is an online demo. It seems that it works according to my expectations.

Comment: OK, I've tested and it still produces the wrong results. The expected outcome is: { 1 }
{ 3 };
{ 5 };
{ 7 };
{ 2, 4, 6, 8 };
{ 1 };

Comment: @SuperJMN yea, when I posted this answer it was not clear in which group the value 7 belongs. Feel free to modify this answer so that it fits your needs!